# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context for List<char>

Tags: c#, linq

```
var initials = Queries["SurnameInitial"].Split(',').ToList();
var chars = initials.SelectMany(y => y.ToCharArray());
filter.And(s => chars.Contains( s.Surname.First()));
query = query.Where(filter);
var count = query.Count(); //Exception here.
```

I'm getting exception

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Any help?

Comment: I'm guessing it's something that `filter` is set to before this block of code is executed.

Comment: Will it help if you change to this: `var initials = Queries["SurnameInitial"].Split(',');
var chars = initials.SelectMany(y => y).ToArray();`?

Answer (score 0):

It´s very hard to help without knowing where came some of variables there, but i wrote this sample to try help you find the solution, check it out:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HuRPpI

Keep in mind that you cannot join a data in memory with the data in database.